# load page and execute javascript in a url

Tags: javascript, url, webview

Hello wonderful stackoverflow users.

I have a question about url loading.

In many browsers and web viewers, there is the functionality to load a url to a website, but also a url to execute javascript.

```
Load a website: http://www.google.com
Load a script: javascript:alert("Hello!");
```

My question is, is there a way to load an http request as well as a javascript.

The answer is most likely no, but I want to confirm because I can't find any resources that describe this.

I was thinking it would be something like:

```
http://www.google.com&&javascript:alert("Hello!");
```

but the problem is, of course, this is not correct.

The reason why I am doing this is to provide a url that once it is clicked, it will also execute a certain javascript function. This will be in Android.

I appreciate any response, and understand that the answer may be no.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting for a result from this?

Comment: Hello Mikey. I would like the page to load and the javascript function that is on the site to be executed as I call it. I guess it doesn't make sense for it to be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on whether you have control of the page being linked to.  If you cannot modify the source of the linked page, then the answer is quite simply, no.

But, if it is your page, you can pass arguments in the hash, and then read the hash when the page loads and execute script accordingly.

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (location.hash.indexOf("doSomething") > -1) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Gilly. I think so as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript when a page loads using Browser plugins, such as GreaseMonkey for Firefox, or TamperMonkey for Chrome.

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
- http://tampermonkey.net/index.php?version=3.11&ext=dhdg&updated=true